# Ubuntu not booting up freezing in between boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot

Sometimes when I boot into ubuntu it's loading icon is offset like a webpage that the css hasn't fully loaded

[image]

it froze like this then when i clicked "Enter" I got back what looked like the terminal but when I typed couldn't see any text appearing so I did a force shutdown by holding down the power button and then rebooted it.

Now it doesn't go past this point.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you tagging as dual-boot? You don't mention a second os anywhere in your post... In any event you may need to upgrade your kernel

Comment: I have windows also installed but I don't think its related to the issue at hand.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: Use a live usb and select the upgrade option